# What genre of music is "Gobi Moon", composed by Dave Randall after 2014?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I love this piece, and I've been craving similar music! The vocals feel like yipping, but liberating and uplifting!  Here's the [video](http://www.splitmusic.co.uk/placements/cathay-pacific-online-advert) and [another clip](https://adsspot.me/media/tv-commercials/cathay-pacific-airways-miss-adventure-796f809a6933).

The composer is [English](https://www.linkedin.com/in/dave-randall-a0035ab/?originalSubdomain=uk), but the genre of singing feels Asian which makes sense because

1. these advertisements are for Cathay Pacific, a Hong Kong airline. This music must've been composed after 2014.
2. "Gobi" may be alluding to the Gobi Desert in East Asia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is contemporary uptempo electronic indie pop --of one flavor or another (there are endless subgenres, with new ones created daily). I think **indietronica** or **dreampop** might be the closest matches, although neither is necessarily an exact fit.

The vocals are more like **ambient pop**, but the background is too uptempo.